# Scala generics in function return value

Tags: scala, generics, scala-generics

I have these classes defined.

```
trait ResultTrait {
}
case class PostResult (
  @Key("_id") id: String,
  success: String,
  errors: Seq[String] = Seq.empty
) extends ResultTrait

case class PostError (
  message: String,
  errorCode: String
) extends ResultTrait
```

This won't compile. It gives error "Required T, but found PostResult (or PostError)".

```
def postLead[T <: SFDCResult](accessToken: AccessToken):
        Future[T] = {
     // depends on response from request, return PostResult or PostError
}
```

Comment: When you make a method generic you're saying that the caller gets to decide what `T` is (possibly given some constraints), not you as the implementer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Travis Brown has already stated, it looks like you're trying to express the variability of the return type (i.e. "it's either a `PostResult` or a `PostError`") through generics, when really all you need is the parent trait.

Assuming your `SDFCResult` was an anonymization error where you meant to use `ResultTrait`, I would use the following:

```
// Make the trait sealed so we can only have our two known implementations:
sealed trait ResultTrait {}
...
// Two subclasses as before
```

And then your method should just be:

```
def postLead(accessToken: AccessToken):Future[ResultTrait] = {
  // depends on response from request, return PostResult or PostError
}
```